# Printing answer of two doubles gives the answer 0.00

Tags: c, printing, while-loop

I am trying to add two doubles and print out the value of the numbers. I am new to programming in C and am sure this is a simple mistake somewhere I am not seeing. Here is the code:

```
 while(count < 2){
    scanf("Enter the letter for the operation. %c", &entered);

    get = getchar();

     if(get == 'a'){
        printf("Please enter two numbers \n");
        scanf("%f %f", &num1, &num2);

        answer = num1 + num2;

        printf("Answer = %.2f", answer);
        count++;
    }
```

I get the character and if the user entered a it will do addition for example.

The output I get is: 
'

Please enter two numbers

2

3

Answer = 0.00

Comment: What do you think the *"Enter the letter for the operation."* there in `scanf` does? Can you see it displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely overlooked that I should have been using %lf in my scanf statement for type double and not just %f.

Comment: Please read how to actually produce a [mcve](/help/mcve) for your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you check the return of scanf.

Second, make sure you add a space at the start of your format strings; this tells `scanf` to skip any whitespace when looking for a float.